# Nokia Lumia 520 Videos

Tags: video

How do I play videos on my Nokia Lumia 520 because the memory shows the videos but the video tab shows nothing please help.

Comment: *Where* does the "memory show the video"? Which video tab are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Those video's codec or extension may not be supported by phone that's why video tab doesn't show anything even it they are present on your phone (in phone or memory card). Try downloading app like VLC player from store and then try to play those videos from that app it self or from folder where they are present on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

install moliplayer app. it supports almost every known video types.